# Can magnetic permeability be exactly equal to 1 in Gaussian system of units?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

In the Gaussian system of units, $\mu >1$ for a paramagnetic substance, while for a diamagnetic substance $\mu<1$. For free space it exactly equal to unity. My question is: is there any substance or material for which permeability is also equal to unity?

Answer (score 1):

Non unity relative permeability $\mu_r$ implies that the material can be magnetized once immersed in an external magnetic field. The magnetization of any material is due to its atomic net currents which comes from their sub-atomic orbiting or spinning kinetics. Any material (even air) can be magnetized to a degree, although very negligible that you would say that its $\mu_r$ is unity.